# React Redux doesnt dispatch action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I recently try to implement redux in my react app.

I have a container called SignIn who instantiate a mapDispatchToProps and connect him to the component.
SignIn render a component called SignInForm (code below).

In this component, we call an action witch update a redux state by calling an action nammed "SignInUser" witch update him from the value "false" to "true"

the problem is that when I'm trying to call the this.props.action on my script, this just return [that object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JazlG.png)

Here is the SignIn component code :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { 
        signInUser: () => {
            dispatch(signInUser())
        }
    }
}

function SignIn() {
    return (
        <div className="skr-flex column between-v centered-h stretched">
            <div className="col-retracted stretched-h p-m skr-flex row between-h centered-v">
                <Logo />
            </div>
            <SignInForm signInUser={signInUser} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn)
```

And here just the part where the dispatch is supposed to opperer

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

handleClick(event) {
    this.props.signInUser()
}
```

However I have absolutely no errors, all the rest of my code seems to work properly

I have an idea on why it doesn't work but I'm a pure beginner on redux (and stackoverflow by the way) and just need some help to clarrify my thought

I hope I've been pretty clear about my problem

Thank's in advance guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signInUser` action will be provided to your component as a prop. Hence, You need to access it from props.

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="skr-flex column between-v centered-h stretched">
        <div className="col-retracted stretched-h p-m skr-flex row between-h centered-v">
            <Logo />
        </div>
        <SignInForm signInUser={props.signInUser} />
    </div>
)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn)
```

Comment: Thank's !

But it returning the error "props is not defined"

I don't understand why I'm getting this

Answer (score 1):

you should call props.signInUser, props is your component argument

```
function SignIn(props) {
    return (
        <div className="skr-flex column between-v centered-h stretched">
            <div className="col-retracted stretched-h p-m skr-flex row between-h centered-v">
                <Logo />
            </div>
            <SignInForm signInUser={props.signInUser} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Shame on me it works perfectly !

thanks a lot to you and @rishi

This problem was maybe a bit stupid but being a beginner in react and redux I still have a little trouble with the basics !